# Replicate input scroll on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to replicate a input horizontal scroll on a div element, so whenever the user move along the input the div element scrolls exactly the same as the input.

My problem is with Chrome as it seems the input has a different scroll behavior, causing the scrollLeft value to be different in both elements. In Firefox it works as expected.

Is there any way to achieve this in Chrome **without using jQuery or other libraries**? or am I asking the impossible?

```js
var theTextDiv = document.getElementById("the-text");
var theText = document.getElementById("the-text-input");

function keepScroll(txt) {
  theTextDiv.scrollLeft = theText.scrollLeft;
}

theText.addEventListener("blur", function() { keepScroll("blur"); });
theText.addEventListener("change", function() { keepScroll("change"); });
theText.addEventListener("focus", function() { keepScroll("focus"); });
theText.addEventListener("input", function() { keepScroll("input"); });
theText.addEventListener("keydown", function() { keepScroll("keydown"); });
theText.addEventListener("keyup", function() { keepScroll("keyup"); });
theText.addEventListener("scroll", function() { keepScroll("scroll"); });
theText.addEventListener("select", function() { keepScroll("select"); });
```

```css
#the-text {
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 98px;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#the-text-input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<input type="text" id="the-text-input" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the above code on Chrome 77 on a Mac and it works as expected, there's no gap between both elements, and I'm starting to think this is a Windows problem rather than a Chrome problem

**EDIT(2):**

After restarting my PC all work as expected (seriously) maybe some chrome cache was causing to have a weird behavior

Comment: Is that the actual code? It seems to work fine on Chrome 77.

Comment: I have tried it with Chrome and it work.

Comment: Works in Chrome 77 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with paddings and borders on the `input` and/or the `div`, and as it looks like it's working fine in Chrome 77, you either forgot to add some code in the example you posted or the default styles for those elements are also playing a role here.

In any case, my suggestion would be to remove margins, paddings and borders from both elements and adding a wrapping `div` with those instead (red example).

You can also use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), keep those styles and avoid the wrapper, but `padding` behaves differently in an `input`, as content in the padding area is not visible (blue example).

Lastly, your code to update the scroll was not working properly on blur, as when the event fires the scroll on the input hasn't been reset to 0 yet. Wrapping it with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) solves the issue. Additionally, the latter will also make the update much smoother and in-sync.

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const input = document.getElementById('input');

function updateScroll() {
  // Scroll not updated on blur without requestAnimationFrame
  // or setTimeout:
  requestAnimationFrame(() => text.scrollLeft = input.scrollLeft);
}

input.addEventListener('blur', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('change', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('focus', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('input', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('keydown', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('keyup', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('scroll', updateScroll);
input.addEventListener('select', updateScroll);

const textAlternative = document.getElementById('text-alternative');
const inputAlternative = document.getElementById('input-alternative');

function updateScrollAlternative() {
  // Scroll not updated on blur without requestAnimationFrame
  // or setTimeout:
  requestAnimationFrame(() => textAlternative.scrollLeft = inputAlternative.scrollLeft);
}

inputAlternative.addEventListener('blur', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('change', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('focus', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('input', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('keydown', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('keyup', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('scroll', updateScrollAlternative);
inputAlternative.addEventListener('select', updateScrollAlternative);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Moved styles here: */
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px auto 0;
}

#text,
#input,
#text-alternative,
#input-alternative {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  outline: none;
}

#text,
#input {  
  /* Removed margin, padding and borders: */
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#text-alternative,
#input-alternative {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Keep styles here thanks to box-sizing, but behaves differently: */
  border: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px auto 0;
}


#text,
#text-alternative {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* No need to keep it visible unless you want to scroll manually too: */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
</div>

<label class="box">
  <input id="input" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />
</label>

<div id="text-alternative">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<input id="input-alternative" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />
```

Comment: @rulogaf You're welcome :) Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if it answers your question ;)